# How to drag and drop between swt and JavaFX 11

Tags: javafx, drag-and-drop, swt, javafx-11

JavaFX 11 has made the CustomTransfer type internal, so all of my classes which could transfer between JavaFX and SWT now break. It seems as though JavaFX now only supports the six transfer types of Text, RTF, HTML, URL, Image and File.

I can solve the problem by BASE_64 encoding my objects into a byte array and using the TextTransfer type, however, this feels very hacky and not at all the intended solution to this problem, especially since also drop accpetance information is lost because the type cannot be determined until drop.

Extending one of the six transfer types cannot work because they do not have public constructors.

What is the proper solution to be able to drag and drop a custom object between SWT and JavaFX now that the CustomTransfer type has been made internal? Additionally, as a curiosity, why did JavaFX even deprecate then internalize that class in the first place?

Comment: Is the problem on the JavaFX or the SWT side? If JavaFX, note that [`DataFormat`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DataFormat.html) has both a [public constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DataFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String...)) for creating new instances and a [static method](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/DataFormat.html#lookupMimeType(java.lang.String)) for obtaining already-created instances.